# AutoCompleteTextView in android

Tags: android, eclipse, autocompletetextview

In Android AutoCompleteTextView only show show dropdown when we entered first letter correctly .What I want is when I enter any letter sequence in the string available it should show the drop down.for example "January" is in my array so when i enter "anu" in AutoComplete field it should show "january" in drop down.Please help.
Thank You

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely going to have write your own `Filter` and attach it via a `TextWatcher`. This response has an example of regex in an `AutoCompleteTextView`: [Android AutoCompleteTextView with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691356/android-autocompletetextview-with-regular-expression) and here is another regex/java example: [How can I perform a partial match with java.util.regex.*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469231/how-can-i-perform-a-partial-match-with-java-util-regex)

EDIT: You will need to extend ArrayAdapter in order to override getFilter() and return your custom filter.

So you are going to have something like this:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
   }
});

public class RegexFilter extends Filter{

   ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
   public RegexFilter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
      mAdapter = adapter;
   }
...
   @Override
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(constraint);
      Matcher m = p.matcher("");
      List listOfMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (String curMonth : months) {
         m.reset(curMonth);
         if (m.matches || m.hitEnd()) {
            listOfMatches.add(curMonth);
         }
      }
      FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
      results.values = listOfMatches;
      results.count = listOfMatches.size();
      return results;
   }

   @Override
   protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
      mAdapter.addAll(results.values);
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}

public class PartialArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   ...
   RegexFilter mFilter;
   @Override
   public TimedSuggestionFilter getFilter() {
      if(null == mFilter)
         mFilter = new RegexFilter(this);
      return mFilter;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to find setFilter() and getFilter() functions in AutoCompleteTextView Class.my android API Level is 8

Comment: @pyus13 edited my code. Sorry the getFilter() function is in ArrayAdapter. I recommend doing an ArrayAdapter example (maybe like this one: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications). Adapters are an important part of Android...