# How to make autocomplete text view accept only already written phrases

Tags: java, android, android-studio, autocompletetextview

I already made a list of phrases for
autocomplete text view in android studio and i want the autocomplete to accept only phrases in this list
For e.g if my array contain sarah,mike,adam
And i wrote in the autocomplete text view omar .. the autocomplete text view will not accept it ..it will delete it .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoCompleteTextView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648347/autocompletetextview-in-android)

Comment: I didn't .. it's just for show suggestions even if  write the second letter .. i edited my question to understand what i exactly want . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, PHRASES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] PHRASES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
```

Also you should take a look of the android developer site: [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView)

Comment: This is just how to make autocomplete text view
 What i want is the autocomplete text view accept only phrases in my arrays .. for e.g in your code if i write China it won't accept it .. is that even possible in android studio?